# is there a way that i can convert this dataframe into a datatype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

already clean a lot of information into this, and i'm feel stuck now, if anyone can give some ideas and how to proceed i will apreacite so much.

[image: dates column]

later i need to join with this:

[image: dates and time column]

and timezone abbr. ¿there's a library or something that can handle datetypes like this?

my desired output is something like this: 2022-05-04 18:00:00 but i have this:

[[image: have this]]

Comment: please show the desired output, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: sorry for that, and thanks for your answer  - the desire output is some like this: 2022-05-04 18:00:00

Comment: then you should handle you dates as strings, concat them and then use datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should make sure your dates are strings in order to concatenate them. You can do this like that:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(str)
```

After that you can use [python's datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to format it as dates.

```
date = 'May-02-2022'
time = '9:00 AM'
timestamp = a + ' ' + b
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(timestamp, format='%b-%d-%Y %I:%M %p')
print(timstamp)

>>> Timestamp('2022-05-02 09:00:00')
```